# Knockout JS Multiple buttons each having a click function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to have a bunch of buttons that when you click the button it alerts you its name. Currently my code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
   <button data-bind="text: name, click: alertName(name)"></button>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    items: [{"name":"Burt"},{"name":"Sam"},{"name":"Greg"}]
});

function alertName(name){
     alert(name);
}
```

I'm running into a handful of errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return items }"

Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return alertName(name) }"

Message: alertName is not defined

Is there a simple way to achieve this in knockoutjs?
I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hny7295e/

Comment: If you haven't already, I strongly recommend checking knockout's official tutorial if you are going to do KO work. http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a ViewModel. Take A look at the documentation on [ViewModels](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html). The `alertName` method should be on this ViewModel. As the method is not on the individual item you need to use `$parent.alertName()`. The current item in the loop will be passed by knockout to the `alertName` method.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.items = [{"name":"Burt"},{"name":"Sam"},{"name":"Greg"}];

    self.alertName = function (item) {
        alert(item.name);
    };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2uondxp/)